# Prescription writing from an HTML page using jsp

Tags: jsp, printing

I am building a **doctor's application** where in he can build an ***online prescription***.
He will be provided with some textboxes and some select lists and when he finally clicks on print, a prescription prints out with the letter head of the hospital.
I want to know whether there are some ***preexisting applications*** like this.
If not can u please tell me ***how can i print an HTML page into the letter head of the hospital***.
Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: The basic problem that i am facing is that the doctor's letter head has a header and a footer. So how can i make sure that the data to be printed is within that particular area of the letter head where it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an activex control to handle printing properly.

Comment: What is that exactly.? thanks for the answer but can u please give me some more description of this?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to print from the browser without the browser asking you to confirm and choose the print settings. But you can generate an HTML page which is suitable for printing and use JavaScript to make the confirmation dialog box appear automatically.

If you need more control, you may also generate a PDF document (with birt or JasperReport, for example), and display this PDF document in the browser page. The adobe plugin will take care of displaying and printing the document.

Regarding the letter head of the hospital, either you include the hospital heading in the generated HTML page or PDF document, or you ask the doctor to use a printer containing paper already having the hospital header, pre-printed.

Comment: thanks JB Nizet. I will try this and will get back to this question if there is another problem.